# MSMQ Vista x64

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, msmq, transactionscope

I am running Vista Ultimate x64 on my system. I have an application that works fine on a remote server to send messages to the MSMQ instance running on it. When I bring the application to my local system and attempt to send a message it doesn't send, but doesn't error out either. I even tried setting up a local MSMQ instance and the same happens with that one - no errors, but no messages either. The queues are transactional and the code itself is transaction-based.

Any suggestions? I tried implementing the journal option (assuming this is like logging) and it doesn't record anything.

I dug through event viewer and the only error I am seeing (actually it's a warning) is:

*MSDTC encountered an error (HR=0x80000171) while attempting to establish a secure connection with system [ComputerName]*

All the standard stuff has been checked like firewalls, is MSMQ running, etc and when I put the app, unaltered, on the remote server it works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with MSMQ directly. You are using transactioning queuing which requires MSDTC to be setup and configured correctly.